# Exporting customized UITableViewCells into UIImage

Tags: ios, uitableview, uiimage, export

I have a `UITableView` with a set of `UITableViewCell`s in it - each of the cells contain a `UIView` which shows some graphics in a context.
 What would be the best way to export these cells into one `UIImage`?

Thanks

edit 1: I know how to create an image from the viewable area of the table, but this table scrolls out of the screen and I would like to create a `UIImage` of all of the cells, not only those you see.

Comment: Is this a one-time thing for debugging/marketing or something users will have to sit through when using the app?  How many cells will there be?

Comment: It will be a feature in the app. we are talking about around 4(?) cells , each 200 pixels high or so. I think it'll be pretty fast, if it'll work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should be able to do this by telling the view's layer to draw into a custom graphics context, then creating a bitmapped CGImage from that context.  Once you have a CGImage, you can create a UIImage from it.  It would look roughly like this:

```
// Create a bitmap context.
CGColorSpaceRef colorSpace = CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceRGB();
CGContextRef bitmapContextForCell = CGBitmapContextCreate(nil, cell.bounds.size.width, cell.bounds.size.height, 8, 0, colorSpace, kCGImageAlphaNone);
CGColorSpaceRelease(colorSpace);

// Draw the cell's layer into the context.
[cell.layer renderInContext:bitmapContextForCell];

// Create a CGImage from the context.
CGImageRef cgImageForCell = CGBitmapContextCreateImage(bitmapContextForCell);

// Create a UIImage from the CGImage.
UIImage * cellImage = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:cgImageForCell];

// Clean up.
CGImageRelease(cgImageForCell);
CGContextRelease(bitmapContextForCell);
```

That's how to create a image for each cell.  If you want to create one image for all your cells, use your table view instead of the cell.

Comment: Hi, thanks for helping. I tried this for the tableview and got what I have right now - only the viewable table is drawn (it is scrolling outside of the screen).

Comment: Well, you may have a hard time getting it to draw all the cells for the entire table because UITableView doesn't create all the cells ahead of time.  It only creates them on demand, when they scroll into view.  So if any any given point you were to ask UITableView to draw all of its cells, it wouldn't have them available for you.  Perhaps you should ask your table view controller for all the cells in the table, create an image for each one, then draw all the images into a single bitmap context and make an image from that.

Comment: thnx, would explicitly calling drawrect on each do the trick?

Comment: No, that would draw into the current graphics context, not your bitmap graphics context. You wouldn't be able to capture the output that way.

Comment: By the way, if this answer is satisfactory, you should consider accepting it officially, so other people will know this question has an answer.

Comment: Thank Ryan. Turns out the problem was the "cell.bounds.size.width, cell.bounds.size.height" portion of the code. if you like to render cells from outside the screen you need to put the requested size in there, not use the cell.bound property.