# Simple resizing image

Tags: iphone, resize-image

I've been trying to use a method commonly used to resize an image.  Without using this method, here is the code that takes a url of an image.

```
NSData *data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:url];
UIImage *img = [[UIImage alloc] initWithData:data];

cell.imageView.image = img;
```

This works fine.  But when I try to use this method:

```
-(UIImage*)imageWithImage:(UIImage*)image scaledToSize:(CGSize)newSize;
{
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContext( newSize );
    [image drawInRect:CGRectMake(0,0,newSize.width,newSize.height)];
    UIImage* newImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
    return newImage;
}
```

and call it using this:

```
UIImage *scaledImage = [self imageWithImage:img scaledToSize:CGSizeMake(10.0f,10.0f)];
```

then putting into my table like this:

```
cell.imageView.image = scaledImage;
```

Nothing shows up. Is there something I'm missing here?

Answer (score 1):

This is similar to [Exporting customized UITableViewCells into UIImage](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4168484/exporting-customized-uitableviewcells-into-uiimage/4169320#4169320)

Here's what you need to do in your -imageWithImage:scaledToSize: method, modified from my answer to that question:

```
-(UIImage*)imageWithImage:(UIImage*)image scaledToSize:(CGSize)newSize
{
    // Create a bitmap context.
    CGColorSpaceRef colorSpace = CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceRGB();
    CGContextRef bitmapContextForScaledImage = CGBitmapContextCreate(nil, newSize.width, newSize.height, 8, 0, colorSpace, kCGImageAlphaNone);
    CGColorSpaceRelease(colorSpace);

    // Draw the image's layer into the context.
    UIImageView * imageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:image];
    [imageView.layer renderInContext:bitmapContextForCell];
    [imageView release];

    // Create a CGImage from the context.
    CGImageRef cgScaledImage = CGBitmapContextCreateImage(bitmapContextForScaledImage);

    // Create a UIImage from the CGImage.
    UIImage * scaledImage = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:cgScaledImage];

    // Clean up.
    CGImageRelease(cgScaledImage);
    CGContextRelease(bitmapContextForScaledImage);

    return scaledImage;
}
```

Comment: shouldn't it be `UIImage *scaledImage = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:cgScaledImage];`?

Comment: Thanks..I get an error on this line
    [image.layer renderInContext:bitmapContextForCell];
saying request for member "layer" in something not a structure or union

Comment: Yeah, this code has been adjusted from some actual code, and I haven't compiled and run it.  The general idea should work, though.  That said, I was trying to get the layer of a UIImage, whereas I needed to be getting the layer of a UIImageView.  I've updated the example code to correct that.