# How can I remove a UIView with rounded corners from its parent view?

Tags: cocoa, cocoa-touch, rounded-corners, quartz-2d, cgcontext

I'm creating an iPad app for 3.2 and later. My app has an overlay view which has a semi-transparency that makes everything below it darker. In the middle of this view I am chopping a hole in this semi-transparency to let part of the background filter through unscathed, with this code:

```
- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect {
    CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
    CGRect intersection = CGRectIntersection(hole.frame, rect);
    CGContextClearRect(context, intersection);
}
```

Additionally, the 'hole' view has rounded corners, applied via:

```
self.layer.cornerRadius = 4.25;
```

This works great except for one small problem - these rounded corners are not taken into account, so the hole that gets chopped out has square corners instead of rounded. I need to fix this, but I have no idea how. Any ideas, examples, thoughts?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's how I ended up getting it to work. This produces a hole with the same frame as the 'hole' UIView, cutting it out from self (UIView). This lets you see whatever is behind the 'hole' unhindered.

```
- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect {
    CGFloat radius = self.hole.layer.cornerRadius;
    CGRect c = self.hole.frame;
    CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();

        // this simply draws a path the same shape as the 'hole' view
    CGContextMoveToPoint(context, c.origin.x, c.origin.y + radius);
    CGContextAddLineToPoint(context, c.origin.x, c.origin.y + c.size.height - radius);
    CGContextAddArc(context, c.origin.x + radius, c.origin.y + c.size.height - radius, radius, M_PI_4, M_PI_2, 1);
    CGContextAddLineToPoint(context, c.origin.x + c.size.width - radius, c.origin.y + c.size.height);
    CGContextAddArc(context, c.origin.x + c.size.width - radius, c.origin.y + c.size.height - radius, radius, M_PI_2, 0.0f, 1);
    CGContextAddLineToPoint(context, c.origin.x + c.size.width, c.origin.y + radius);
    CGContextAddArc(context, c.origin.x + c.size.width - radius, c.origin.y + radius, radius, 0.0f, -M_PI_2, 1);
    CGContextAddLineToPoint(context, c.origin.x + radius, c.origin.y);
    CGContextAddArc(context, c.origin.x + radius, c.origin.y + radius, radius, -M_PI_2, M_PI, 1);

        // finish
    CGContextClosePath(context);
    CGContextClip(context); // this is the secret sauce
    CGContextClearRect(context, c);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

What you're trying to do is called masking.  You can use Core Graphics to mask the current graphics context.  See Apple's documentation on the subject here:

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/GraphicsImaging/Conceptual/drawingwithquartz2d/dq_images/dq_images.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP30001066-CH212-CJBHDDBE

Comment: That looks in reference to images - I need to mask a view. Is it appropriate to render a View into an Image just to do operations?

Comment: Definitely.  You can modify the code I posted here to do so:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4168484/exporting-customized-uitableviewcells-into-uiimage/4169320#4169320

Answer (score 0):

If you change the `cornerRadius` property of a layer, you must also set `clipsToBounds` to `YES` on the associated view in order for the content to be clipped to the rounded corners.

Comment: clipsToBounds is whether or not you may draw objects outside the bounds of the receiver view. In other words, can your draw a UIView's subviews outside of the parent UIView's bounds. Not sure how that will help here..

Comment: The `cornerRadius` gets incorporated into the clipping path (in rough terms), so you must have clipping enabled in order for it to take effect on your content.

Comment: I just tried this and it doesn't seem to fix the corners..is there something else you have to do to make it work?

Comment: This was exactly the solution I was looking for.