# Android View with 'hole' in it

Tags: android, layout, android-linearlayout, android-camera

I've created a custom camera view for Android. I have overlayed the camera preview with a semi transparent LinearLayout with a TextView and Button. Now I need to punch a 'hole' in the middle of the view so you can see the underlying camera preview clearly . The hole then acts as a frame guideline allowing the user to 'frame' the photo.

I succeeded with the iOS version by creating a view and cutting out a rectangle from the view as demonstrated [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4349400/how-can-i-remove-a-uiview-with-rounded-corners-from-its-parent-view). How would I go about doing the same thing for Android?

Comment: Typically I manage to solve the issue immediately after posting the question. Do this by adding a SurfaceView to your layout and set the background to be transparent. 

            <SurfaceView android:id="@+id/spacer"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
                android:layout_height="320dp"
    android:background="@drawable/transparent_background">
   </SurfaceView>

Comment: Now you are thinking with portals.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're going to need to start with the hole and build around it.  Layers in Android are additive, there is no way to punch a hole.

Answer (score 3):

Use [SurfaceView](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/SurfaceView.html).

> "the SurfaceView punches a hole in its window to allow its surface to
>   be displayed"

Answer (score 0):

This is the code I'm using:

```
setContentView(mCameraPreview);
addContentView(mOtherView, new LayoutParams
        (LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
```

Areas that are transparent in mOtherView will allow the camera preview to show through.